# Как вынести часть кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from collections import Counter


def sleight_of_hand(k, matrix):
    c = Counter(int(x) for row in matrix for x in row if x != ".")
    return sum(x <= 2 * k for x in c.values())


def main():
    k = int(input())
    matrix = (input() for _ in range(4))
    result = sleight_of_hand(k, matrix)
    print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Как и куда можно вынести 2 * k?

Comment: А зачем вообще выносить `2 * k`?

Comment: Мне это нужно, чтобы приняли задачу, так сказали сделать

Comment: Вы можете сделать фукцию, которая будет умножать k на 2 - формально вы запрос выполните. Но без понимания, зачем вам так делать сказали, вы услышите, что вы сделали не то.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 2 * k выполняется на каждой итерации - можно вынести

Answer (score 3):

Замените вот это:

```
return sum(x <= 2 * k for x in c.values())
```

на это

```
k2 = k * 2
return sum(x <= k2 for x in c.values())
```

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку `k` вообще в чистом виде не используется, как вариант можно вообще сразу умножить его на 2 после ввода, но лучше таки переобозвать переменную, чтобы потом не путаться при отладке где у вас что:

```py
def sleight_of_hand(k2, matrix):
    ...
    return sum(x <= k2 for x in c.values())

def main():
    k2 = 2 * int(input())
    ...
    result = sleight_of_hand(k2, matrix)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Sop Но скорее всего от вас требовалось всё же то, что приведено в другом ответе - просто вынести переменную из цикла (вернее, из генераторного сокращения, в данном случае).